# What is the integration of $\int \frac{\tan x}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> What is the integration of $\int \frac{\tan x}{x}dx$?

I have tried substitution, integration by parts, and other methods I could think of but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe that an answer exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if antiderivative is elementary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285346/check-if-antiderivative-is-elementary) **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362554/integral-int-frac-tan-xx-dx

Comment: Check a closely-related post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58966/solvability-in-differential-galois-theory

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is that this is not an integrable function.

Comment: Put this in comment section

Comment: Wow, you answered your own qn

Comment: @rash So? That's perfectly acceptable.